# Rails: Stripe appears to work but no charge is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails app where Stripe is set up similar to [this](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails) documentation.  When I hit the "Pay With Card" button and enter the test card information it says it's successful, then gives me an error message saying:

```
No route matches [POST] "/charges/new"
```

Even though my routes are like this:

```
resources :charges
get 'charges/shipping'
get 'charges/address'
post 'charges/update_order'
```

My `charges_controller` reads like this:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

   ...

  def new
    @order = current_order
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = current_order.total * 100
    @user = current_user
    @order = current_order

    if @user.stripe_customer_id
      customer = @user.stripe_customer_id
    else
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )
      @user.update_attributes(stripe_customer_id: customer.id)
    end
    @order.update_attributes(order_status_id: 2)
    @order.update_attributes(date_placed: DateTime.now)
    # OrderMailer.order_placed(@order.user, @order).deliver_now
    session[:order_id] = nil


    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => @user.stripe_customer_id,
      :amount      => @amount.to_i,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.permit(:subtotal, :tax, :shipping, :total, :order_status_id, :user_id, :date_placed, :shipping_choice)
  end
end
```

If I manually insert a `post "charges/new"` into the `routes.rb` it says it's successful, but it redirects to the same page (indicating a `Stripe::CardError`) and no charge registers in the stripe dashboard.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the end of your `#create` method? We see the end of your `rescue` block, but not the end of your `#create` method. It's supposed to redirect after a success. Also, if there is an error, you are supposed to `render :new` not `redirect_to new_charge_path` which will erase all the form values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to change the code on the form to `charge_path` instead of `new_charge_path` so it would hit the `create` action.  Even though this was different from the Stripe documentation it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not permitting the 'stripeToken' parameter in your `order_params`. Because of camel-case that might be a little fiddly, but make sure you're allowing that param with something like:

```
params.permit( :"stripeToken" …
```

Without this, that parameter is null, and would give you a Stripe failure.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't eliminate any of the errors or make the charge go through.

Comment: Have you tried :stripe_token perhaps? I can imagine Rails doing something where it converts camel case to underscored. At this point I'd probably add the `byebug` gem and then add a `byebug` line in there just to see what I was getting as params.

Comment: The same would also apply for `params[:stripeEmail]` - I just get the impression that's nil.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part here in your controller:

```
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
```

You should remove `redirect_to new_charge_path`, and simply just let Stripe render the error message. No need to redirect upon error. Stripe takes care of the error-handling for you (which is one of the things making Stripe great).

Currently, your `redirect_to` is being treated as *the* path after each successful purchase. Not just on errors.

**Update**

Upon further looking at your code. You don´t seem to actually have a `redirect_to` after each successful purchase. So regardless, you should remove the `redirect_to new_charge_path` because it´s currently arbitrary to `=> e`. It might look like it has something to do with the Error handiling, cause it's below that block, but in fact it doesn't. You should instead add `redirect_to successful_path` or `render :success` (for instance) right above the `rescue Stripe::CardError =>`. And then let Stripe handle **(or rescue)** failed attempts to make a purchase, as explained before.

Comment: Unfortunately, this removal didn't change the error behavior at all.  :(

Comment: Hmm.. Thats weird. Because what's actually happening is that your redirect is the de facto path after each purchase. After looking close at your code, you don´t seem to actually have a path that stripe will be redirected to after each successful purchase. So regardless, you should remove the `redirect_to new_charge_path` and add a redirect right above the ` rescue Stripe::CardError ` to where you want the user to end up after a successful charge.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your client side code, I can't be sure - but it sounds like your client side code is trying to POST to `/charges/new` - which doesn't exist - so it's failing.  I'd suggest you update your client side code to POST to the route you want to have handle that, and then continue debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your server to reload the routes. Run `rake routes | grep charges` to verify that you see `POST /charges/new`.

Wait, I know why. You are supposed to **GET** `/charges/new` and **POST** to `/charges`. Show us your view code, specifically the form submission URL address.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions